# There is a circular import error shown in the terminal while compiling the code in DJANGO

Tags: python, django

This is the code in the urls file in project folder 'helloproject':

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include(helloapp.urls))
]
```

This is the code in the urls file in app  'helloapp':

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.fun,name='fun')
]
```

This is the code in the views file of 'helloapp':

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def fun(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

Comment: Can you show the whole error traceback

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.